# Get rowcount for a filtered TClientDataSet

Tags: c++, vcl, dbexpress

I'm using a TDBGrid and a TClientDataSet together in a C++ VCL application.

The client dataset contain data for customers. If I create and apply a filter of the clientdataset, the filtered data is shown in the grid. However,  checking the clientdatasets RecordCount property always return the total amount of records, not the one shown after filtering.

Any idea how to get that number?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, checking the RecordCount property in the debugger in a CalcFields callback may not be reliable. It seems the callback is called multiple times and the recordcount property is only set at the end.

So the answer to the question seem to be to use the RecordCount property of the client dataset.